How to integrate google play integrity api in flutter?
I've been trying to integrate Google Play integrity into my app, I've linked the project to the Google Play console, but now I'm stuck at the API requests part. I've read the documentation but I dont know how its going to work.
Doc link: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup
I want to integrate this is flutter. Please help me.
I didn't understand the documentation. I just linked the google play console project.
